# bizCharts set an integer as tick

Tags: reactjs, integer, echarts, bizcharts

**I want just show integer,just like minInterval in echarts**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3kgo.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
formatter: (val: any): any => {
  if (Math.floor(val) === 0) return null;
  return val;
},
```